# How do I create a slideshow of words and images in Android Studio?

Tags: android

I would like to display 50 words, one at a time, and after each word display the corresponding image.
How do I do that in Android Studio?
I have created a string array

```
strings = new String[]{"1","2",.....,"50"}
```

and I have uploaded 50 images in the drawable hdpi folder.
How do I create a slideshow that displays one word at a time, says the word out loud twice and displays the corresponding image after that?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a widget known as AdapterViewFlipper which works perfectly well if you have to do a slideshow.
An AdapterViewFlipper takes an adapter object as it's argument. You would want to create your custom adapter object extending from the BaseAdapter class. In your case, you would have to set each position in the adapter by overriding the getView(int position, View convertView ViewGroup parent). So a simple logic would be:

```
if (position == 0) {
    // use text views to display this
    then display number;
    say word out twice loud;
} else if (position == 1) {
     // use an image view here
     then display corresponding image;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, Sunil, but I am trying to create an app, not a widget.

Comment: I'm not sure I understood. AdapterViewFlipper is the widget which you can use inside your app. You do not have to create this widget - it is already bundled in with Android. You just have to create your custom adapter objects.

Answer (score 0):

You can combine the images in an array and use SliderView.